# What are the secrets of geth --unlock. How can I tell if an account is locked?

Tags: go-ethereum

geth --unlock and how it's used.
 I've looked in depth at all of the documentation I can and came across this problem, or failure to understand some of it really.
By the way, I'm using this on a Mac.

```
instance: Geth/v1.8.11-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.10.3
```

For example.
./geth account list
returns the following.

The first one, #0 was created in 2016. The next two, this week.

```
Account #0: {c9b74488b8e699b54803464a33d57cfff7eb052c} keystore:///Users/robert/Library/Ethereum/keystore/UTC--2016-05-27T11-31-47.551960099Z--c9b74488b8e699b54803464a33d57cfff7eb052c
Account #1: {b8baff0dcc88b9bf7aed45966938a30e2ab23ce4} keystore:///Users/robert/Library/Ethereum/keystore/UTC--2018-06-18T13-40-57.053229334Z--b8baff0dcc88b9bf7aed45966938a30e2ab23ce4
Account #2: {bf7042c963111a96bd4c8d86c179576ddfc07cb8} keystore:///Users/robert/Library/Ethereum/keystore/UTC--2018-06-19T06-11-21.589039961Z--bf7042c963111a96bd4c8d86c179576ddfc07cb8
```

Now, only account #1 and #2 can be unlocked. It's one I created with geth, using ./geth account new

To unlock this account, I use this

```
geth --unlock  0xbf7042c963111a96bd4c8d86c179576ddfc07cb8 --datadir=/Users/robert/Library/Ethereum --password password.txt
```

That works, BUT. accounts #0 and #1 will not unlock - because I have no idea what or if they are even password protected. locked or unlocked? How can I tell?

So, the first address, address #0 is actually a Blockchain.info created address, and is actually Unlocked. I never locked it when created. If indeed I ever could lock it.

```
Unlock account 0xc9b74488b8e699b54803464a33d57cfff7eb052c
Passphrase: 
Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase
```

The second address, #1, I don't know. I suspect I've accidentally created it. No idea if it's locked or unlocked.
So, using ./geth attach I do this.

```
> personal.unlockAccount('0xb8baff0dcc88b9bf7aed45966938a30e2ab23ce4', null, 1)
Unlock account 0xb8baff0dcc88b9bf7aed45966938a30e2ab23ce4
Passphrase: 
true
```

And as you see, that works. Fortunately when I created that account, again it must have been with ./geth, I used my usual password.

So the question remains, **how do I tell if an address is locked or unlocked?**
How do I add an address to that keystore other than by creating it with ./geth address new? Which didn't happen with the #0 address, because that's a Blockchain.info created address. How did it get into the keystore?

As I think address #0 is unlocked, the error 'could not decrypt key' is actually telling me that it's already unlocked. Interesting stuff.

Comment: send a transaction, if you get an error that the account is locked, then the account is locked

Comment: all your accounts in `keystore` directory are encrypted with AES 128 bits. You have to know the password, otherwise you lost them. Ethereum doesn't save accounts in plain JSON text file, however, there is a functionality to do so in `geth`

Comment: you have some misunderstandings, the term "locked" means the account wasn't decrypted and it is not ready to send a transaction. the term "unlocked" means you have provided the password, the account was decrypted now, and you can send transactions. If you "unlock" an account it will become locked again after 5 minutes (or so, I don't know the exact time) and you will have to unlock it again if you didn't use it. Locking is the mechanism that `geth` uses to prevent the user forgets his console with an unlocked account , to avoid security problems. See locking as Desktop screensaver.

Comment: Thanks, yes now I understand. This works, because I did password protect that account number. geth --unlock 0xbf7042c963111a96bd4c8d86c179576ddfc07cb8 --datadir=/Users/robert/Library/Ethereum --password password.txt